# What is a short hand for random variable X, Y independent?

Tags: probability, notation, normal-distribution, independence

In some of the textbook problems, it would say, suppose X and Y are zero mean, unit variance independent Gaussians...

I would usually just write $$X,Y \sim \mathcal N(0,1)$$ and this is a nice short hand form of this sentence, but how do I express independence? I used to write COV(X,Y) = 0 until I realized that COV(X,Y) = 0 does not imply independence

Comment: Your short form does not express independence.

Comment: Just write "$X$, $Y$ are independent". There's no need of a symbol for everything.

Comment: @Najibidrissi I did not say there had a to be symbol for everything, I was just wondering if there existed something out there. See, you are saying there doesnt have to be a symbol for everything, another post is saying there indeed exists something that everyone agree upon. The amount of hate this thread has received is unconscionable and really shows the shallowness of a lot of people here (obviously not you)

Answer (score 5):

You often see "i.i.d." used for "independent identically distributed". So you could write $$X,Y \textrm{ i.i.d.} \sim \mathcal N(0,1)$$

Answer (score 5):

I've had several profs who sometimes write $X\perp Y$ to mean $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

Comment: Nobody said anything absurd like that. It's just a shorthand that people use sometimes. If you don't like it, don't use. I don't appreciate the sarcasm.

Comment: It was "correct" because the people who used it agreed to its meaning and the contexts provided no misunderstanding.

Comment: It looks like OP is being intentionally obtuse. Your answer was perfectly understandable and correct. OP chooses to ignore what you are suggesting. I got a similar response.

Comment: @ProjectBacklog In this context it doesn´t mean orthogonality. See here:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notation_in_probability_and_statistics

Comment: @Calculus In other contexts it does not mean independence. See http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12128/what-does-orthogonal-mean-in-the-context-of-statistics